# DateTime Comparison .isBefore(), isAfter() does not work on .toUtc() converted time in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

I am using dart core DateTime package. This gives correct result when not using .toUtc();
but when I convert .toUtc(); it gives this behaviour

My code:

```
final DateTime now = DateTime.now().toUtc();
final DateTime startTime = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 6, 49);
final DateTime endTime = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, 6, 50);
print('current time $now');
print('start time $startTime');
print('end time $endTime');
print('is current time before start time: ${now.isBefore(startTime)}');
print('is current time after end time: ${now.isAfter(endTime)}');
print('');
print('');
```

Expected Result:

```
current time 2023-05-05 06:48:26.455Z
start time 2023-05-05 06:49:00.000
end time 2023-05-05 06:50:00.000
is current time before start time: true
is current time after end time: false
```

My output:

```
current time 2023-05-05 06:48:26.455Z
start time 2023-05-05 06:49:00.000
end time 2023-05-05 06:50:00.000
is current time before start time: false
is current time after end time: true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is both StartTime and EndTime are non UTC time. Based on your current timezone, the result you got was correct.

To get the expected result,
use `DateTime.utc` constructor to create StartTime and EndTime.

```dart
  final DateTime startTime = DateTime.utc(now.year, now.month, now.day, 6, 49, );
  final DateTime endTime = DateTime.utc(now.year, now.month, now.day, 6, 50);
```